# What is a good 3'' BNF that can be used indoors and outdoors?

Tags: quadcopters, recommendations, under-250-grams

I am looking to get a new quadcopter that will work in a variety of places. I want it to be a 3'' drone so that I can fly it both outside and inside. I would prefer if it had prop guards or ducts of some sort, but that's not necessary. I want a drone with decent performance and a good analogue FPV system. I already have a good transmitter (Jumper T16 Pro) and good FPV goggles (Skyzone Sky02X) so I am looking for a BNF. I'm looking for a drone that won't break the bank, but will be good quality and will last a long time.

Comment: It's difficult to find a quadcopter which is powerful enough to fly outdoors in the wind and light enough to not break things inside.

Something along the lines of a cinewhoop would be the closest I can think of, but there are better quads for both indoors (whoop, tinyhawk) and outdoors.

Comment: You really don't want to fly a 3" indoors even in a gym, and prop guards won't help anything fast enough to be fun outside. Just spend the $50 for a dedicated indoor whoop.

Comment: @RobinBennett I'll definitely do that once I have more money, but for now I'm just looking for something to fly outdoors and, if I need to, indoors.

Comment: The Blade Inductrix is really nice, easy to use, and it's easy to install your own "all-in-one" analog FPV on. However, it's not durable or heavy enough to fly in very gusty wind. I just like it because being popular, it has plenty of online support. I think the tiny whoop is a bit stronger overall and comes with its own camera, but I don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your budget I would look at these two options:

Diatone Taycan: this is a cinewhoop style quad that is more than powerful enough to fly outside as well. It will not be as nimble as your typical freestyle quad but if that is not what you are looking for you can't go wrong with this one.

HGLRC Sector 132: This option will be cheaper as the Taycan but seems to offer good value for the money. By default there are prop guards that allow you to fly indoors (not ducts) and if you remove them, you can start freestyling outdoors.

Just based on the type of build, the Taycan should be more sturdy and last longer than the Sector 132. That being said, this is a hobby where you can destroy any type of quad if you start pushing your limits and try out more challenging moves.

Regardless of your choice, it is a good idea to implement throttle scaling when you fly indoors. This can be done on your remote and tied to a switch.